# Does Unity's OnApplicationPause work on iOS/Android?

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine

I'm working on Unity for iOS&Android application which gets user's location in background. I want to catch moment when app becomes background, but `OnApplicationPause` never called.

I placed only `Debug.Log()` call inside `OnApplicationPause` method to ensure if event is triggered but it's not.

My code:

```
public class GPSService : MonoBehaviour {

   ...

    void OnApplicationPause(bool paused){
      Debug.Log("Paused");
      if(paused){       
       UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene("Background");
      }
    }
}
```

Where is the problem? And how to fix it?

I tested this behavior on Unity 5.4.4f1 and 5.5.1p4.

Tested devices: iPhone 4s, Doogee X5 Max (Android 6.0.1)

Comment: It's not working on Android or iOS?

Comment: Ok. Can I see how you implemented the function and what's inside of it? Also, what makes you think it's not working or getting called? Did you use `Debug.Log`?

Comment: @Programmer Sorry for incomplete question. I placed only Debug.Log inside `OnApplicationPause` method to ensure if event is triggered.

Comment: @Programmer Why I think it's not working. For example for iOS. In Xcode console I see both `applicationDidEnterBackground` and `applicationDidBecomeActive` events and nothing logs between them.

Comment: You said you also test this on Android and it does not work. Can I you post the function and code inside it. Don't type it. Copy and paste that directly.

Comment: @Programmer Updated question with code. App neither logs "Paused" message and nor loads new scene.

Comment: Can you comment **everything** in that function except for the `Debug.Log` then put `Handheld.Vibrate();` under it. Let me know if the device vibrates.

Comment: @Programmer Both iPhone 4s & Doogee X5 Max (Android 6.0.1) haven't vibrated. :'(

Comment: This is weird it is supposed to be called. Is your `GPSService` script enabled? Is the GameObject `GPSService` script is attached active? If not then I don't think it will be called.

Comment: @Programmer Just tried listen for `OnApplicationFocus` event, and iPhone vibrated!

Comment: @Programmer `GPSService` is main functionality module and it fully worked before I tried to add background processing.

Comment: Interesting. Please note that there are `OnApplicationFocus`, `OnApplicationPause` and `OnApplicationQuit`. These do behave differently and I suggest you read about all of them. I ask you to file for a bug report if `OnApplicationPause` is not working.

Comment: @Programmer Thanks for your help! I will try on more phones and more versions of Unity and add new issue to UnityIssueTracker if needed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try use OnApplicationFocus(bool)

On Android, when the on-screen keyboard is enabled, it causes a OnApplicationFocus( false ) event. Additionally, if you press Home at the moment the keyboard is enabled, the OnApplicationFocus() event is not called, but OnApplicationPause() is called instead.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationFocus.html

Comment: The question was how to fix OnApplicationPause not a replacement that has different functionality

Comment: Answer should be considered off-topic.